# AutoCompleteBox or FilterComboBox for Windows 10 WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

The old WPFToolkit had an AutoCompleteBox but the toolkit seems to be gone or just outdated. I downloaded the archive code from codeplex.com and compiled but after several days of configuring and testing it, it is just not working well.

I am looking for a open source custom control for XAML that implements a similar feature or better yet one that can filter a combobox. I am using an MVVM development approach with a lookup table as the ItemSource and assigned the SelectedValue the ID and not the display name. The list is over 3000 items, so just displaying them is not an option. Also they are not grouped so filtering by category first is not an option.

Q: does such custom control exist or sample code?
thanks in advance

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.SpeciesTitleText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <input:AutoCompleteBox
                          IsTextCompletionEnabled="False" 
                          IsTabStop="False"
                          MinimumPopulateDelay="200"
                          FilterMode="Contains"
                          MinimumPrefixLength="3" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Species, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSpeciesLookup.Id,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          ValueMemberBinding= "{Binding DisplayMember}"
                </input:AutoCompleteBox>
          </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the WPFToolkit NuGet package (AutoCompleteBox)?

Comment: If you are referring to the one listed as author (JenniLe,Shimmy), then Yes I have but it has not been updated in last 6 years (2012). I could not get it to function correctly in a DataGrid, plus it seems to be just a package of the existing code I downloaded from codeplex. It is partial working but I am finding I have to add my own relaycommands and eventargs just to make it communicate with the viewmodel. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Also tried the other NuGet Package DotNetKit.Wpf.AutoCompleteComboBox but it produced side effects in a the above Datagrid as well. On a signal view, it worked well, but a filter of one combobox erased an other comboxes for other records in the same datagrid except the ones that had the same filtered value.